# Insert form checkbox at bottom of taxonomy edit term page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, taxonomy-meta

I have created a custom taxonomy 'provider'. I have also added a checkbox to the add and edit term pages. The problem is that the checkbox I have created is showing at the very top of the page - right under the 'Edit tag' header. I want it to show at the bottom - above the submit button.

(Note the functions are being called within a class hence the reference to $this)

```
add_action('provider_add_form_fields', array($this, 'category_metabox_add'), 10, 1);
add_action('provider_edit_form_fields', array($this, 'category_metabox_add'), 10, 1);

public function category_metabox_add($tag) { 

    $term_val = get_term_meta($tag->term_id, 'show_on_provider', true);
    $term_val == 1 ? $checked = 'checked' : $checked = '';

    echo '  
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="show_on_list">Show on list?</label>
        <input name="show_on_provider" id="show_on_provider" type="checkbox" value="1" '.$checked.' />
        <p class="description">WIll this show on the list?</p>
    </div>
    ';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My bad - the mark up for the edit page is different than add. Used this instead

```
add_action('provider_edit_form_fields', array($this, 'category_metabox_edit'), 10, 1);

// add image field in edit form
function category_metabox_edit($tag) {

    $term_val = get_term_meta($tag->term_id, 'show_on_provider', true);
    $term_val == 1 ? $checked = 'checked' : $checked = '';

    echo '<tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="show_on_provider">' . __('Show on list?') . '</label></th>
        <td>
        <input name="show_on_provider" id="show_on_provider" type="checkbox" value="1" '.$checked.' />
        </td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: You should look into using the checked() function provided by WordPress - it would shave one line of code off your function, not much I know but when these functions are provided it is better to make use of them

Comment: Thanks! This saved me a bit of time. I was similarly using the same function for both the "add" and "edit" screens, and was just about to dig into the markup.